# PHP Glob, exclude directories containing .files in their name

Tags: php

I am using glob to find directories inside the current one where my index file is. Inside it i am saving html pages extracted from EXCEL and they create folders directories ending in .files Is there a way to glob all directories but exclude those ending in .files?

Here is my code as it's currently:

```
<?php
// set to current directory 
$dir = '';

// directories only. ignore files, etc.
foreach(glob($dir.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $folder){ 
// do not include wordpress directories
  if (($folder != '*') && ($folder != 'ΦΥΛΑΚΕΣ ΠΡΑΤΗΡΙΩΝ.files') && ($folder != 'wp-includes')) { 
  // list directories and their links
?> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dir."/files/".$folder;?>"><?php echo $folder;?></li> 
<?php 
  }
} 
?>
```

EDIT: As you can see i can exclude specified folders but i want it to exclude automatically all folders ending in .files as i said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)-function to do the following:

```
<?php
// set to current directory 
$dir = '';

// directories only. ignore files, etc.
foreach( glob( $dir.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR ) as $folder ){ 
// do not include wordpress directories
  if( ($folder != '*') && (substr( $folder , -6 ) != '.files') && ($folder != 'wp-includes') ){ 
  // list directories and their links
?> 
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $dir."/files/".$folder;?>"><?php echo $folder;?></a>
    </li> 
<?php 
  }
} 
?>
```

Comment: This did the job that i wanted it to do i just have one question. This will only remove folders ending in .files right? It won't delete any other folder that i create in there?

Comment: Yeah that's what i wanted, by remove i meant from the displayed list, my bad. This is exactly what i wanted! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

I will rather use preg_grep function

```
$src = glob("*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$nomatch = preg_grep("/.*\.files$|^wp\-includes$/i",$src,PREG_GREP_INVERT);

foreach($nomatch as $folder)
{
    echo "print ".$folder;
}
```

The formating after selection is simple

Comment: I'm kinda new to PHP so please excuse me for asking. Which part of my code do i replace with yours in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the message, I do not how to use it properly, I write it here

```
<?php
$cur = getcwd();
chdir($dir);
$src = glob("*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);
chdir($cur);
$nomatch = preg_grep("/.*\.files$|^wp\-includes$/i",$src,PREG_GREP_INVERT); 

foreach($nomatch as $folder)
{
?>
   <li><a href="<?php echo $dir."/files/".$folder;?>"><?php echo $folder;?></li>
<?php
}
?>
```